# Is it possible to draw a Bézier curve with variable width in SVG?

Tags: svg, bezier

I wrote a small library to draw signatures in HTML apps which uses Bézier curves with variable width (based on drawing speed) to simulate hand writing effect: http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad.

Is it possible to draw such curve, i.e. Bézier curve with different width at its beginning and its end in SVG?

Comment: Are you trying to recreate ballpoint pen, brush strokes or calligraphy pen with SVG?

Comment: Yup. The library I wrote allows you to export drawn signature to JPEG/PNG images. I was wondering if I can export it somehow to SVG as well.

Answer (score 1):

NO. SVG does not currently support variable width stroke.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to export such curves to svg, but you'd have to represent the shapes as filled paths. SVG doesn't support variable width stroking (yet).

Comment: Thanks! HTML canvas element doesn't support variable width strokes yet as well, so currently I'm calculating approximated length of a curve and then draw a lot of filled circles (their number depends on the calculated length) along its coordinates with diameter equal to desired width. It works pretty well for raster images - do you think it might work with SVG as well? I'm not sure if zooming in wouldn't expose how to curve is actually drawn :/